# spf record paramenter "all" equals to "+all"?

Tags: dns, spf

I need to parse spf record.
Please advice `v=spf1 all` means the same as`v=spf1 +all`?
Is such syntax allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [RFC7208 section 4.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.6.2) says this about qualifiers:

> The possible qualifiers, and the results they cause check_host() to
> return, are as follows:
>
> ```
>   "+" pass
>   "-" fail
>   "~" softfail
>   "?" neutral
> ```
>
> The qualifier is optional and defaults to "+".